# Read/Write .ini in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ini

Is it possible to read/write variables to an .ini file in java-script and save it to a common directory such as the desktop. PLEASE avoid examples with php because my html will be running natively in the browser, and I would like to have access to the .ini files created.

Comment: I don't think that's possible. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server).

Comment: Not in the client, but yes on the server with NodeJS: https://github.com/shockie/node-iniparser

Comment: @elclanrs - does that code run in a browser (which is what the question is directed at)?

Comment: @jfriend00: Well no, but the actual parser is very small, so with a bit of work it could parse ini files on the browser from a `get` ajax request for example, or a simple string.

Comment: @elclanrs - I was under the impression that the OP wants to store per-user state locally on the client machine.  They don't describe the real problem they're trying to solve (a common issue here on SO) so it's hard to know what they're really trying to do.

Comment: @jfriend00: Yup, that too. Question in _not_ clear, I just read "ini", searched for "parse ini js" and copy/pasted the link. I'm lazy.

Answer (score 2):

You can't write to a file on the desktop from a browser with Javascript for security reasons.

You can save similar state that one would put in a .ini file to either a cookie or to HTML5 Local Storage and then retrieve that info from future web pages.

If you describe the problem you're actually trying to solve, we could better advise what options are available.